# scanf() in while loop. Put a space before % doesn't work

Tags: c

```
double bet = 0;
do
      {
        printf("How much would you like to bet? The minimum bet is $5.00: ");
        scanf(" %.2lf",&bet);
      } while (bet < 5);
```

My scanf just takes value once and goes into infinite loop. I have read many posts, and found the general way to solve this is put a space before %. I did this, but the problem still exists. Say it first read bet = 4, and it is supposed to ask me to enter a number again, but it just keeps printing "How much would you like to bet? The minimum bet is $5.00: ". Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `scanf` format string.  Your compiler might have warned about it.  The `.` isn't allowed.  As a result, the `scanf` call is returning `0` and is not consuming any characters.

Try changing it to this:

```
double bet = 0;
do {
    printf("How much would you like to bet? The minimum bet is $5.00: ");
    scanf(" %lf", &bet);
} while (bet < 5);
```

It would also be a good idea to check the return value from `scanf`.  It should return the number of values successfully decoded.

Comment: @user4593157 please also check the return value from `scanf` ***every*** time you use it. This would have told you the input was not converted.

Comment: @Weather Yeah, I normally would check the return value.  I'll leave that to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Is .2 is required in your code. It is showing warning as a use of . in the code. Try removing it. Then it is working fine. ie use only %lf

Comment: sorry, just a typo. I have added it.